# using jquery timepicker for duration with symfony

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, timepicker

I am trying to make the jquery timepicker work with symfony.

In my form I have :

```
    ->add('workingDuration', 'datetime', array(
            'label'=>'Temps de travail',
            'required' => false,
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'attr'=>array
            (
                'class'=>'timepicker'
            )))
```

and in my javascript a simple $('.timpicker').timepicker().

But I have the following issues :
- if my database field type is of type 'time', I get

```
 'Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object'
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return ($value !== null)
            ? $value->format($platform->getTimeFormatString()) : null;
    }
```

- if my form field is of type 'time', the timepicker just does not launch
- if the database field is of type datetime, as well as the form type, I have a full date stored to the database and when reading back this element, the timepicker addon does not recognize the format and does not initiate properly.

How can I do to make it work. Actually I'm looking forward to only store a short duration, hence the need for the timepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally figured out of to answer the dilemna.

Basically, I needed to convert a time / a string to a datetime object and vice versa so as to make the jquery addon time picker work to store a duration.

The answer is :

1. use time in the database :  * @ORM\Column(type="time", nullable=true)
2. create a data Transformer which transforms a datetime object to time string and vice-versa :

   namespace AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

   class DateTimeToDurationTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface

   {
       /**
        * @param mixed $dateTime
        * @internal param mixed $value
        * @return string
        */
       public function transform($dateTime)
       {
           if (null === $dateTime) {
               return "";
           }

   ```
       $time = $dateTime->format('H:i:s');

       return $time;
   }

   /**
    * Transforms a string (number) to an object (issue).
    *
    * @param  string $duration
    * @return mixed|object
    */
   public function reverseTransform($duration)
   {
       if (!$duration) {
           return null;
       }

       $dateTime = new \DateTime($duration);

       return $dateTime;
   }
   ```

   }
3. create a custom TimePicker type to add to your forms

   namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
   use AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer\DateTimeToDurationTransformer;
   use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

   class TimePickerType extends AbstractType
   {

   ```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
       $transformer = new DateTimeToDurationTransformer();
       $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
   }

   public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
   {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
               'invalid_message' => "La durée indiquée n'est pas au bon format",
               'attr' => array(
                   'class'=>'timepicker',
               )));
   }

   public function getParent()
   {
       return 'text';
   }

   public function getName()
   {
       return 'timepicker';
   }
   ```

   }
4. register the TimePicker type in your services

   services:
       timepicker.type:
           class: %timepicker.type.class%
           tags:
               - { name: form.type, alias: timepicker }
5. use the newly created type in your form:

   ```
   $builder
               ->add('workingDuration', 'timepicker', array(
                           'label'=>'Temps total de travail',
                           'required' => false,
                           'attr'=>array
                           (
                               'class' => 'timepicker',
                               'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                               'data-placement'=>"top",
                               'title'=>"Indiquez le temps total de travail consacré à la recette si il diffère du temps de travail cumulé des étapes de production.",
                           )))
   ```

That's what it takes but it's working now!!

Also don't forget to use the timepicker with timeFormat HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/datatype-datetime.html

```
time [ (p) ] [ without time zone ]  times of day only   8 bytes     00:00:00.00     23:59:59.99     1 microsecond
time [ (p) ]     with time zone     times of day only   12 bytes    00:00:00.00+12  23:59:59.99-12  1 microsecond
```

Method `->format()` is for **DateTime** object. (see. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Change in Entity / document type of **workingDuration** field from "time" to "**datetime**"
(http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html)

Comment: this is my third bullet point : still not working ! If I do this, a complete date is saved in the database, then a complete date is reloaded in the field and the timepicker widget won't understand its format and won't initialize properly...

Comment: From your question is not clear whether you want to have a DateTime object or only Time was that a valuable hint to further help;)

Comment: Hi Pawel! I just want a time. If i need to store a datetime that can be read by the timepicker, good enough, but is seems the timepicker can't read a full date brought back from the database. When I set my parameters to time type, the timepicker does not initialize...

Comment: Timepicker supports only time, if you want to support the DateTime object, use this: `http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/`

Comment: ahah, I'm sorry if I'm difficult to understand. I want to use time. Time only. The issue is when I set the form field type to 'time', $('#myField').timepicker() does not work. It does if the type is set to 'datetime'. But I don't want datetime, I want time.

Comment: In the database you need to have a datetime or timestamp (if you want timestamp in DB, in the form change `input => 'datetime'` to `input => 'timestamp'`). I hope I was able to help and examples will work :)

Comment: I'm getting crazy with this... So you make it work with ->add('wordingDuration', 'datetime', array('input'=>'timestamp')) and @ORM\Column(type="datetime"). Can you confirm? If I do that I have the php error from above, call format on a non-object.

Comment: Add this to Your form: http://pastebin.com/AcZdPFyu

And this to Entity: `@ORM\Column(type="datetime")`

Comment: thanks so much for trying to help! But now I have a timepicker with a hh:mm:ss tt format, which is not suitable for a duration. the 0 is 12:00:00 AM instead of 00:00:00. And I can't get rid of the AM/PM even though I put timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss' in my timepicker regional settings.

Comment: You're wrong concepts and therefore you can not get the desired effect, date / timepicker and DateTime / timestamp in database is used to keeping the date! You need `DateInterval` http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: found it! see new answer, the use of a datatransformer solved it. Thanks for your help!